# Why is the following code not terminating?

Tags: c

Why is the following code not terminating at all?

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  main("hello",32);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile correctly ?

Comment: Consider the statement 'printf("Hello World\")'. The ending double quotes is missing. When you use a '\' the character following it is not used in its normal sense (also called escape sequence). Moreover, you should not pass any  arguments to 'main'

Comment: The code shown in the question doesn't compile. Various closely related bits of code will compile, but until you add an `n` after the backslash in `printf("Hello world\");`, or remove the backslash (or add some other appropriate character(s) after the backslash), your code doesn't compile, despite any assertions to the contrary. Current versions of C require an explicit return type on `main()` — it should be `int main(void)`, for example. As written, the compiler can't check the recursive call for validity (no prototype), so it accepts the unusual calling arguments of 'simple string, integer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will generate a compilation error "Extra parameter in call of main" 
if run without any parameter in main then it will be a recursive call for the main function that is why it is non terminating.

Answer (score 8):

There is a recursive call to `main()` function (on line 4 in your code) which leads to unbounded recursion.

Comment: But there's only one call,

Comment: main() is calling itself and it is an unbounded recursion.  You may want to study recursion to understand what is happening.

Comment: @Anurag Read about recursive function calls. When 'main' is called first time it makes call for other 'main' and so on.

Comment: @ GAURANG ok, and will it matter if how many times I pass arguments to the main functions?

Comment: @AnuragChhabra: It is possible to make the compiler check for the number/type of arguments, but the code you have pasted has no such check.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would never reach the `return 0;` statement... because the `main` function will call itself before then. The second time the code runs, it will call itself again, then when `main` is run again, it will call itself before reaching the return statement... 
This will continue forever.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is giving compilation errors. The correct code could be -

```
int main()
{
   printf("Hello world");
   main();
   return 0;
}
```

It is going in infinite loop because 'main' is recursively calling itself and there is no terminating condition.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are two things here:

1. The standard says there are only two ways to write `main`:
   `int main(void) {}` and `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {}`. You are following neither, which makes
2. your `main` function accept an *unspecified* number of args. And thus you should **not** expect that your `main` function does not accept any arg.

As a result of the second point, even this would compile and run:

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  main("hellow",32, "cow", 3.14);
  return 0;
}
```

Write `int main(void)` and see what the compiler has to say about the recursive call.
HTH.